# Vertical Indicator in Ellipse-shaped Progressbar

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a gauge in which I need an ellipse shaped progress bar.  I would like the progress bar indicator to move from the bottom of the ellipse to the top.  I can get it to work from left to right with no problem.

[image]

Here is the style code:

```
<Style TargetType="ProgressBar" x:Key="HalfCircle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                <Grid x:Name="gridRoot">
                    <Ellipse x:Name="PART_Track" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="150" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="150" Clip="M0.5,0.5 L153.5,0.5 L153.5,76.5 L0.5,76.5 z">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <MultiBinding>
                                <MultiBinding.Converter>
                                    <converter:ProgressBarIndicatorConverter/>
                                </MultiBinding.Converter>
                                <Binding Path="Foreground" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                <!--<Binding Path="Orientation" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>-->
                                <!--<Binding Path="Background" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>-->
                                <!--<Binding Path="Minimum" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="Maximum" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>-->
                                <Binding Path="IsIndeterminate" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="PART_Indicator"/>
                                <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="PART_Indicator"/>
                                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="PART_Track"/>
                                <!--<Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="PART_Track"/>-->
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <Decorator x:Name="PART_Indicator" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
                </Grid>
                <!--<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">

                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>-->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here is the relevant XAML:

```
 <ProgressBar x:Name="pbPos" Height="158" Width="158" Margin="8,6,0,0" Orientation="Vertical" Style="{StaticResource HalfCircle}" Foreground="{StaticResource RotationLightGreen}"  />
```

As you can see by the commented out code, I have been trying several things to no avail...

---

> > > UPDATE<<<

I ended up creating a usercontrol with a clipped progressbar and some dependency properties in the code-behind as follows:

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ProgressBar x:Name="pbEllipse" Orientation="Vertical" Background="Transparent" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Height="150" Width="150" Margin="0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ProgressBar.Clip>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure IsFilled="True" IsClosed="False" StartPoint="0,75">
                    <BezierSegment Point3="75,0" Point2="33.5786476135254,0" Point1="0,33.5786399841309"/>
                    <BezierSegment Point3="150,75" Point2="150,33.5786399841309" Point1="116.421363830566,0"/>
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </ProgressBar.Clip>
    </ProgressBar>


</Grid>
```

Code-Behind:

```
 public partial class PitchProgressBar : UserControl
{
    public static DependencyProperty ProgressIndicatorColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ProgressIndicatorColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(PitchProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(ProgressIndicatorColorPropertyChanged)));
    public static DependencyProperty ProgressIndicatorValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ProgressIndicatorValue", typeof(double), typeof(PitchProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(ProgressIndicatorValuePropertyChanged)));

    private static void ProgressIndicatorColorPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ctl = d as PitchProgressBar;
        if (ctl != null)
        {
            ctl.pbEllipse.Foreground = (Brush)e.NewValue;
        }
    }

    private static void ProgressIndicatorValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ctl = d as PitchProgressBar;
        if (ctl != null)
        {
            ctl.pbEllipse.Value = (double)e.NewValue;
        }
    }

    public PitchProgressBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

  public Brush ProgressColor
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ProgressIndicatorColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ProgressIndicatorColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public double ProgressIndicatorValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ProgressIndicatorValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ProgressIndicatorValueProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: One option... You could apply a layout transform and just rotate the whole thing 90 degrees?

Comment: Wait, what on earth is the giant multi-binding doing?

Comment: Can't use the rotation...the whole half circle rotates and I want the flat edge to be the bottom.

Comment: The multi-binding is not that giant...I was trying to add other properties to make this work.  They are commented out!  :)

Comment: Ah, didn't notice they were all commented out. Still, would be good to see that code too (then I could test it). I do think though, you might as well just make a new control of your own, rather than try adapt the progress bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This custom Control:

```
    public class FlightGauge : Control
{
    private GradientStopCollection _gradStops = new GradientStopCollection();

    public static DependencyProperty MinValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MinValue", typeof(double), typeof(FlightGauge), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(-100.0, new PropertyChangedCallback(MinValue_Changed)));
    public static DependencyProperty MaxValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MaxValue", typeof(double), typeof(FlightGauge), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(100.0, new PropertyChangedCallback(MaxValue_Changed)));
    public static DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double), typeof(FlightGauge), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, new PropertyChangedCallback(Value_Changed)));
    public static DependencyProperty FillColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FillColor", typeof(Color), typeof(FlightGauge), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Colors.Blue, new PropertyChangedCallback(FillColor_Changed)));

    public Color FillColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(FillColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FillColorProperty, value); }
    }


    private static void FillColor_Changed(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        FlightGauge thisClass = (FlightGauge)o;
        thisClass.SetFillColor();
    }

    private void SetFillColor()
    {
        //Put Instance FillColor Property Changed code here
    }

    public double Value
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }


    private static void Value_Changed(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        FlightGauge thisClass = (FlightGauge)o;
        thisClass.SetValue();
    }

    private void SetValue()
    {
        CalcTabStops();
    }


    public double MaxValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MaxValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaxValueProperty, value); }
    }


    private static void MaxValue_Changed(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        FlightGauge thisClass = (FlightGauge)o;
        thisClass.SetMaxValue();
    }

    private void SetMaxValue()
    {
        CalcTabStops();
    }

    public double MinValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MinValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MinValueProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void MinValue_Changed(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        FlightGauge thisClass = (FlightGauge)o;
        thisClass.SetMinValue();
    }

    private void SetMinValue()
    {
        CalcTabStops();
    }


    private void CalcTabStops()
    {
        _gradStops.Clear();
        if (Value > 0)
        {
            double dLineValue = (1 - Value / MaxValue) /2;
            if (dLineValue > 0.49) dLineValue = 0.49;
            _gradStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Transparent, 0.500));
            _gradStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Transparent, 1.0));
            _gradStops.Add(new GradientStop(FillColor, 0.499));
            _gradStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Transparent,  dLineValue));
            _gradStops.Add(new GradientStop(FillColor, dLineValue +0.001));
        }
        else
        {
            double dLineValue = 0.5 + (Value / MinValue / 2);
            if (dLineValue >= 1) dLineValue = 0.998;
            if (dLineValue == 0.5) dLineValue = 0.5001;
            _gradStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Transparent, dLineValue +0.01));
            _gradStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Transparent, 1.0));
            _gradStops.Add(new GradientStop(FillColor, dLineValue));
            _gradStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Transparent, 0.5));
            _gradStops.Add(new GradientStop(FillColor, 0.501));
        }
        this.InvalidateVisual();
    }

    public FlightGauge()
    {
        BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        Brush brush = null;
        if (Value != 0)
        {
            LinearGradientBrush linBrush = new LinearGradientBrush();
            linBrush.StartPoint = new Point(0.5, 0);
            linBrush.EndPoint = new Point(0.5, 1);
            linBrush.GradientStops = _gradStops;
            brush = linBrush;
        }
        else
        {
            brush = Brushes.Transparent;
        }
        double dX = this.ActualWidth / 2;
        double dY = this.ActualHeight / 2;
        Pen pen = new Pen(BorderBrush, 2);
        drawingContext.DrawEllipse(brush, pen, new Point(dX, dY), dX, dY);
        drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, dY), new Point(this.ActualWidth, dY));
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
    }
}
```

Example Use:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <local:FlightGauge x:Name="fgGauge" Width="200" Height="200" Value="{Binding ElementName=sldValue, Path=Value}" />
    <Slider Name="sldValue" Minimum="-100" Maximum="100" Value="0" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yes I did just that!  I was about to post an update when I saw your solution.  Thanks Kelly.  I will also post my solution which is similar to yours.